# Bosch Dual Fuel Range - blew fuse when moving appliance

Tags: circuit-breaker

We recently purchased and installed a Bosch Dual Fuel Range. We pulled it out from against the wall just enough to get behind it and install a backsplash. When putting back in place there was a blue spark from behind the range then a fuse blew.
We attempted two more times to put it back in place with the same result; blown fuse, circuit reset, blown fuse. Now wondering what our next move should be?

Answer (score 2):

So you have to now move it out further and find out which connection has come loose.

Based on the comment: turn off the supply before doing any work or moving it again.

Make sure that the wire is put back in the correct position.

Also make sure all the terminals are correctly tightened.

Comment: Turning off the breaker first might help also before moving/checking the connections.

Comment: With huge sparks it's probably wise to turn off the gas source as well, while investigating the electrical problem. There obviously some sort of flexible gas line connection, and every time the stove's moved in and out, you're flexing it, creating an _ever so slight_ chance of a leak. You don't want big boom in the house.